# Serializing a HashMap but Text File for input is clearing self every program run. -- Java

Tags: java, io, hashmap, fileinputstream

I have already looked at other problems with these but I don't think any of them match mine. 
The gist of my program is to create a `HashMap` of stocks (key is ticker and value is a `Stock` object) and then when the program ends to export the `hashMap` into a text file. Next time I run the program I would read in the `hashMap` and continue the program. So far all my other functionalists work and I can look at the text file after I run the program and I see some code in there but when I run again the text file is cleared.

I suspect that when I declare a new `FileInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` they are somehow deleting the information in that text file and making it empty.

My code is as follows:

```
     stockInfo = new HashMap<String, Stock>(10000);
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     File file = new File("mp4output.txt");
     fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
     oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
     fis = new FileInputStream(file);
     ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

Is how I declare my I/O streams to read in the hashMap.

Next I try to actually read in the hashMap with

```
           try {
           while (fis.available() > 0)   {
                 Stock test = (Stock) ois.readObject(); 
                 System.out.println("Stock: " + test.getCompany());
                 System.out.println("High: " + test.getHigh());
                 System.out.println("Volume: " + test.getHigh());
                 System.out.println("Low: " + test.getLow());
                 System.out.println("Close: " + test.getClose());
                 System.out.println("Open: " + test.getOpen());
                 System.out.println("Range: " + test.getRange());
                 System.out.println("52 Week average: " + test.getFiftyAvg());
                 System.out.println("Current Price: " + test.getcurrentPrice());
                 }
           }
           catch (Exception ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
           }
```

However it never runs this because `fis.available()` always returns `0` because the file empties itself.

I feel like I have made a very dumb error somewhere but I cannon find it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Create the input stream. Read the data. *Close* the input stream. Create the output stream. Write the data..

Comment: How do I set the behavior to append? I know the implementaion for append for FileWriter but is there such a thing for ObjectOutputStream? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: OOS doesn't open the file, the FOS does. See the FOS documentation [for how to append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)). However, in this case with the same file, you really want process *all* the input and *then* write all the output (after making necessary changes to the data), in which case the truncate behavior works just fine.

Comment: I have encountered a new problem. The program is giving me an IOException due to a bad file descriptor when I call fis.available(). I have never encountered this problem before so what should i do?

Comment: It was because I had closed my input streams too early so they couldn't access the file!

Comment: Close the input stream (FIS/OIS) *after* reading the data - but before creating the output stream (FOS/OOS) or writing any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FileOutputStream will - by default (or, whenever [not created for appending](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)) - truncate the output file. This truncation happens *when* the FOS is created, and before the FIS has a chance to read the data.

A general solution in a case like this - where the input and output are to the same file - is to read *all* the input, close the input stream, and *then* open the output stream and write the new data. In this case the truncation behavior works just fine.

With this in mind, a skeleton may look like this:

```
Map<String, Stock> readStocks (ObjectInputStream ois) {
  // Read all
}

void writeStocks (ObjectOutputStream oos, Map<String, Stock> stocks) {
  // Write all
}

Map<String, Stock> stocks;
// Use try-with-resources (Java 7+) to make life easier;
// the OIS (and underlying FIS) are guaranteed to be closed
// after this block ends.
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
         new FileInputStream(file)) {
  stocks = readStocks(ois, stocks);
}

// Make changes to loaded data
// (i.e. in accordance with user-supplied input)
updateStockData(stocks);

try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
         new FileOutputStream(file)) {
  writeStocks(oos, stocks);
}
```

The Object Input/Output Streams are merely wrappers over the underlying FIS/FOS, but aren't responsible for the lower-level truncation or IO.

Also, while OIS/OOS are probably sufficient for this task, I would recommend using [JSON](http://json.net) because using JSON is "relatively painless" with POJO mappers (e.g. see Gson), and - really why I recommend it - the output is human consumable text.

---

Also, it's not well-defined across operating systems as to how multiple FIS/FOS objects on the same source work. The documentation leaves this vague note (but doesn't specify anything about interactions between FIS/FOS objects where an exception is not thrown).

> A file output stream is an output stream for writing data to a File or to a FileDescriptor. in particular, allow a file to be opened for writing by only one FileOutputStream (or other file-writing object) at a time. In such situations the constructors in this class will fail if the file involved is already open.